# How to record video (with audio) on client side browser?

Tags: flash, web-applications, jquery-plugins, video-capture

thanks in advance for the help!

I have to record video with audio from the client side and save it to my server. I am stuck using the google app engine and have a very limited budget and time to do this.

What can I do?

Do you think the jQuery webcam plugin can record audio? if so, can you please explain how to set it up?

Thank you very much!

I have looked into:

red5: from other stackoverflow questions. But I cannot set up a server
Nimbb API: but it costs a lot of money to do beyond basic. I need to download the files, which is only on paid version and they limit time. I need flexibility between 4 to 10 minutes.

http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/ : this seems the easiest solution, though it doesn't record audio (or maybe I just can't figure it out due to my lack of jQuery/javascript knowledge)

http://haxevideo.org/ for some reason the website is just not loading up in my laptop...and I think it needs a server setup, for which I do not have the flexibility.

I have looked into tutorials online, the solutions I found were comments of people saying they had to set up flash media servers on other places, which is not what I can do.

Thank you again! Your help is incredibly appreciated!

Cheers,

Daniel

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465206/how-to-record-video-on-google-app-engine

Answer (score 1):

The only feasible solution that is acceptable for production is Flash with FMS/WOWZA/Red5
Looking at HTML5 for a complete solution to record and upload user webcam is total waste of time for now.

Comment: Can Html5 now record video and send to php?
Is flash a better way?
Ihow can i do it with flash?