# How to record video on google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I record a video from the client-side browser using google app engine?

This application would be usefull for using the youtube API. Right now, the app I made only allowds for video upload, but I need the users to be able to record video in their browsers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Flash video capture would not work as it needs RTMP server and RTMP can not be implemented on AppEngine (connection time limit).
2. So the only remaining way is to write a Java applet to capture video and upload it as a file. Something like this: http://www.mutong.com/fischer/java/usbcam/

Comment: Thanks! I thought I could use flash. I appreciate the clarification and the solution :)